# Can't get word on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that get the word by getselection method when click, not by user selection, and then show an alert box with the word it's working well with some words, for example:

```
Si potrebbe comumente
```

It works with "potrebbe", but not with "Si".... It means, it works when the word is in the middle of the line, but not with the first or last word of the line...

This only happen when after apply the CheckKnowWords function, without apply this function, it works 100%.

The code is to big to post here, so, to prevent visual polution, I create this jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/fabiobraglin/ww7uLvd1/

ON FIREFOX
InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable

ON CHROME:
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'surroundContents' on 'Range': The Range has partially selected a non-Text node.

When use: 
    range.surroundContents(newNode);

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Check the error console.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: it worked for me, using Google Chrome.

Comment: hi @putvande did you test all worlds? for me the word on begin and at the end of the lines didn't works, and also with some words near , ; . ! : ? ...

Comment: hi, I'm using firefox! and the question is, this is no working for all words, one more information, need to select the word on click!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updated the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/ww7uLvd1/8/  Always use `split(/\s+/)` while trying to split with space

Comment: The problem seems to still exist in Firefox...also in your fiddle the first word no longer seems to be highlighted.

Comment: Your Function does not highlight those fields which are given in var know = "Si;più";

Comment: Hi, this is because he add the word "Si" to know array.... but you are right, the problem still exist!

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: The script must show an alert box when click a word... but it not working when the words are in the begin or at the end of the line... for example, the word Si...

Comment: If you remove the call to CheckKnowWords on body onload... you can see that the selection script works perfectly.... but after aply CheckKnowWords, this is not working well... I believe this is related with append <span operation... but I don't know how to fix it...

Comment: also for the last word you should have 218. in the Know variable with the fullstop.

Comment: Hi... sorry, this didn't solve the problem yet... Forgot the know list... I can't add words on it... in my project it depends if the user know that word or not... when user click on a word, it show an option to add this word to the know array... this is for a language learn system

Comment: Oh you want every word to be alerted????  I tght of only the Know list . Here You go the updated verssion http://jsfiddle.net/ww7uLvd1/12/ . This is my last try.

Comment: Hi Akshay.... it works... could you just explain to me why return sel didn't work in this case? And why need to begin the text after > not in the line bellow? example: <article id="textDescription">Si   If "Si" is in one line below, can't get si when click...http://jsfiddle.net/ww7uLvd1/13/

Answer (score 1):

Firefox seems to have a number of issues with this code.

#### 1) An error is thrown in some cases

According to the documentation on MDN for [Range.surroundContents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents):

> An exception will be thrown, however, if the Range splits a non-Text
> node with only one of its boundary points.

It also suggests another method that will work regardless. Instead of

```
range.surroundContents(newNode);
```

you can use

```
newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
range.insertNode(newNode);
```

This will make it so that you will not get errors on beginning and ending words, like `Si`, or `mondo.`

#### 2) The popup and title show the entire html

They should show the text instead (e.g. `senza` instead of `<span style="border-radius: 4px;border: 1px solid #ffcccc; background: #ffcccc;">senza</span>`). To fix this, you can replace `innerHTML` with `innerText`.

#### More issues

There are a few more issues I found, but this is where it gets tricky. MDN has a warning that [Selection.modify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/modify) is non-standard and doesn't have plans to become standard, so you will get weird behavior between browsers, such as:

- In Firefox, punctuation is being included at the end of the word (e.g. `forti,` or `IATA).`). In Chrome, this doesn't happen. Also, words with punctuation in them seem to work fine in Chrome but not in Firefox (e.g. the word `L'indice` looks fine in Chrome but comes up as `indice` in Firefox).
- In Firefox, clicking on a word that follows a recognized word will instead select the recognized word. For example, if you clikc on `ognuno` where it says `viaggo che ognuno di`, it will catch the word `che`, but this doesn't happen in Chrome.
- The word `Henley` is unique in that it is in bold tags. In the phrase `britannica Henley & Partners`, if you click on either `Henley` or `&` in Chrome you will get `britannica`. In Firefox you will get `Henley`.

You might want to consider changing the technique for finding the word. For example, you're already going through and highlighting all words you're interested in by wrapping them in a `span`. Instead of using Range and Selection, you could use the click event to figure out which `span` you're in, then get the text within that. If your initial checking also excludes punctuation and "words" like &, then you could just select the entire inner text.

Another minor issue I noticed is the HTML uses an unescaped `&` instead of `&amp;`. It probably isn't affecting this example, but in general you'll run into less problems if you properly escape HTML (I think it's mainly just `<`, `>` and `&`, but there's plenty of tools and documentation on that elsewhere).

Here's an [updated fiddle solving the first two issues](https://jsfiddle.net/redbmk/ktptupu6/5/), but they may be obsolete if you end up doing some refactoring to solve the other issues.

Comment: Hi, thk for you answers... You are right ,I will change the word capture method! Well... I 'm creating a <span> on each word, so I can use the onclick option with this.innerHTML....